# How to get which hazelcast instance is running on the node

Tags: hazelcast

I am running many instances of hazelcast with different group names(i.e different cluster) on different nodes. Now I want to make program which runs on a given node and needs to know which HazelcastInstance is running on this node and access its config file. I dont want this program to create any new hazelcast instance. How this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

You can always look up the HazelcastInstance(s) using Hazelcast.getHazelcastInstanceByName if you know the name or get them all using getAllHazelcastInstances.

In some cases you want to get the HazelcastInstance after deserialization (e.g. you send a task to a hz instance using an iexecutor). In this case you can implement the HazelcastInstanceAware interface to get the instance injected.

So it depends a bit on your setup.

The config object you can load using HazelcastInstance.getConfig. The instance doesn't know if the config was made using a xml file, or was made programmatically.

Comment: Sir I have tried getAllHazelcastInstances, but it shows no instances running i.e set size is 0.

Comment: It could be a class loading issue.

And are you sure that on that particular JVM HazelcastInstance(s) are running? If there are none running, you won't see any.